# What is the terminal command for "Show all filename extensions"?

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

Like to build an environment installer and I'm familiar with the **Finder Preferences** checkbox:

[image: Show all filename]

And per "[Show or hide filename extensions on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/show-or-hide-filename-extensions-on-mac-mchlp2304/mac)" but on this stack site, Super User and a Google query I'm unable to find what is the terminal command to select this option through a shell script.

How can I through bash select the checkbox for "Show all filename extensions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleShowAllExtensions -bool true`

False, of course, to reverse.